# select by comparing same column value in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to select row by comparing same column values

Here is my Table

```
  |  X | Y |
  | ---|---|
  |  1 | A |
  |  1 | B |
  |  2 | A |
  |  2 | C |
  |  3 | B |
  |  3 | D |
```

I want select **X** where Y having  A , B. Here X and Y are not unique.

I have tried like

```
   select X from table where Y ='A' AND Y = 'B'
```

but it is returning empty.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select X from table where Y in ('A','B')
group by X having count(*)=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Y cant be A and B at the same time, try IN:

```
select X from table where Y in ('A', 'B')
```

Comment: This query will return `2` and `3` also.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT X
FROM TableName
WHERE Y in ('A','B')
GROUP BY X
HAVING COUNT(*)=2
```

Result:

```
X
--
1
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71a52/1)